# How to get list of remote branches that contain a commit in libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

In git I can run the command:

```
git branch -r --contains '#commit-hash#'
```

Which lists the remote branches that have the commit I am interested in.

I have read the docs on the [libgit2sharp wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-branch) however the example there  local branches?

How can I do the same thing in **libgit2sharp**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the [libgit2wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-branch#displaying-local-branches-that-contains-specified-commit) documentation, you can modify their example code to look like this:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/repo"))
{
    const string commitSha = "5b5b025afb0b4c913b4c338a42934a3863bf3644";
    foreach(Branch b in ListBranchesContainingCommit(repo, commitSha))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Branch> ListBranchesContainingCommit(Repository repo, string commitSha)
{
    var commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>(commitSha);var commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>(commitSha);

    IEnumerable<Reference> headsContainingTheCommit = repo.Refs.ReachableFrom(repo.Refs, new[] {commit});
    return headsContainingTheCommit.Select(branchRef => repo.Branches[branchRef.CanonicalName]).ToList();
}
```